# How to output a variable in JSON?

Tags: json, variables, output

If I have

```
            generic_call: function(path, params){
        this.fetch(
            path,
            params,
            function(data){
                this.last_results = data;
                if($('#log_to_console').is(':checked')){
                    console.log(data);
                }
                **$('#url').** 
                $('#results').text(JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'));
            }
        );
    },
```

and  for **$('#url')**, I have a div as follow:

```
            <div id="url">
               <label>URL Used:</label>
           </div>
```

if I have 
            base_url: 'https://www.faculty180.com/api.php'

and for the part that says:" URL Used: " I want to show the value of base_url, what should I write after:

```
      **$('#url').**
```

Comment: The programming language this is written in / asking about is JavaScript, not JSON.

Comment: ...beyond that, though -- this isn't complete enough to be answerable. I mean, you have a div with a label, but no actual form field. How can we tell you how to access content that isn't there?

Comment: ...or are you saying you're retrieving JSON data and want to put it into the form? Again, you need to be *explicit*, and to have your question be *complete* enough to be unambiguous.